# javascript cancel href link when clicked <a href>

Tags: javascript

If i have multiple links on a website, is there a way that if they are clicked they can be transferred to another website? All the links can be the same, but when either one is clicked they transfer over to the same page.

I'm trying to find an event that cancels the bubble when the event is clicked but can't find one.

Say for example I have

```
   <a href="google.com">google</a>
```

when that link is clicked then it will cancel the google.com transfer and open yahoo.ca

Comment: transfer a link to another website? what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Could you explain it a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could bind a `click` handler that prevents the default, and instead redirects the page, like so.

```
$('a').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    window.location = "http://www.example.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you can have any `href` in link and you click any of links in page, then you need `preventDefault`:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = 'http://yahoo.ca';
});
```